# Regex targets multiple letters as one match, causing problems in my code

Tags: regex

I'm trying to get all letters in a string. But, sometimes, it matches two letters as one match, causing problems.

I think these strings that I'm using have invisible characters in them that are messing things up. Here is one of the strings I was using: "s͏uc͏͏ce͏͏s͏s". If you put that in https://regexr.com/ with ([a-zA-Z])+, it will mark "uc" and "ce" as individual matches. How do I get it to match each character as an individual?

[example of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRo85.png)

Comment: Not invisible, 00034F    ͏   COMBINING GRAPHEME JOINER

Comment: Its a neat way to semi-mask the text

Comment: so I'm assuming if I remove all of those Unicode junk it will work properly? How do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take away the +

The + is a way of denoting one or more elements fitting your sequence constitutes one expression

Comment: edit: ok so i tried that, but now when i eval "Th͏͏e͏ g͏͏ri͏t͏t͏y͏ ͏r͏e͏͏c͏e͏s͏s͏ d͏͏id͏͏n'͏t͏ ͏s͏e͏͏e ͏͏th͏͏e ͏͏be͏n͏͏g͏a͏l͏.".replace(/([a-zA-Z])/), i get "undefinedh͏͏e͏ g͏͏ri͏t͏t͏y͏ ͏r͏e͏͏c͏e͏s͏s͏ d͏͏id͏͏n'͏t͏ ͏s͏e͏͏e ͏͏th͏͏e ͏͏be͏n͏͏g͏a͏l͏."

Comment: With what are you trying to replace the letters?

Comment: I am using regex.

Comment: The replace function will replace all sequences meeting the definition of your regex.

Comment: The whole point of this really is to delete that stupid invisible unicode character, as sln pointed out.

Comment: Did you try deleting the string and retyping it? My suspicion is you copied and pasted it from somewhere else. Just a guess though since I can’t see what you’re doing.

Comment: Yeah well it will always be that way, since it's kinda a hacky program for something.